# After upgrade from Cassandra 3.0.8 to 3.0.14 do we have to run nodetool upgradesstables?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Recently we upgraded 8 cassandra nodes in 2 DC configuration from 3.0.8 to 3.0.14. So, should I have to run nodetool upgradesstables when upgrade 3.0.8 to 3.0.14?. If we should do it, what is the best practice to finish upgradesstables in a fastest way. 
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/NEWS.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is the comment from org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat

```
    // ma (3.0.0): swap bf hash order
    //             store rows natively
    // mb (3.0.7, 3.7): commit log lower bound included
    // mc (3.0.8, 3.9): commit log intervals included

    // na (4.0.0): uncompressed chunks, pending repair session
    //
    // NOTE: when adding a new version, please add that to LegacySSTableTest, too.
```

So, **apparently**, between 3.0.8 and 3.0.14 nothing new appeared regarding sstable versions.

But I did some testing using ccm and I found out that:

- Cassandra 3.0.7 uses mb version for sstables.
- **Cassandra 3.0.8 uses mb version for sstables (still mb!!)**
- Cassandra 3.0.9 - 3.0.14 uses mc version for sstables.

Some other useful reading, although a bit outdated: [one](https://gist.github.com/shyamsalimkumar/49a61e5bc6f403d20c55#file-sstable-format-version-numbers-md), [two](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/1664zsf1xv/how-long-does-nodetool-upgradesstables-take).

A way to check would be to go to your Cassandra data folder and check the sstable files to see which version they use. If different versions are in place, nodetool upgradesstables should be ran. I would run it one node at a time.